# Is there a way to package a dynamic library in the application binary?

Tags: qt, dll

Hi I am developing a Qt application that uses a plugin (dynamic library) and I was wondering if there was a way I could build the application and library in one file (maybe using the QResource feature?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt supports linking plugins statically to your application.  See [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins).

You use the `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN()` macro in your code like so:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qjpeg)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

You also need to list the plugins in QTPLUGIN in your .pro file:

```
QTPLUGIN += qjpeg
```

You may also need to build a static version of Qt yourself - not sure if the prebuilt versions contain static libraries (I don't use the prebuilt code).

Answer (score 0):

You want an application like "DLL to Lib" that will convert your DLL file to a static library. Then you'd link with the .lib file instead of the DLL and you're all set. You can download a trial of one product here:

http://www.binary-soft.com/download.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, make sure not to violate the license of the library.  If the library isn't available as a static library, it might be under the LGPL (or even GPL).  Linking statically in either case would violate the license unless you are releasing your software also under the GPL.